# Unable to log in to chat.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, chat, login

Clicking on login from chat.stackoverflow.com sends me to the login page of stackoverflow.com. I log in, even though I'm already logged in, and it sends me back to chat.stackoverflow.com without being logged in. I've attempted to log out by clicking the link and then clicking the log out button but that didn't work.

I have tested the chat on Firefox 17, Safari 6.0.2 (8536.26.17) and Google Chrome 24.0.1312.36 beta.

I also visited the help page that was recommended and it offered no advice as to what might be wrong. It gave me passes on every mark.

Comment: What browser are you using. ;)

Comment: I was hoping it was literally as easy as hitting a button on the mod/admin side of SO so I didn't give a whole bunch of info. I am using Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312.36 beta.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a modern browser. Have you tried another browser just to rule out a bug in Chrome Beta?

Comment: Not going to lie, your edit made my question slightly more confusing... maybe just me @Jeff Atwood. :D

I tested in Safari and FF and I had the same issue. I logged in to a separate account on SO and I wasn't able to replicate this issue.

Comment: also for the record we don't support beta browsers, by policy. I don't think that's necessarily the problem, but it complicates testing, and creates unnecessary work for those of us trying to help you, so can you please try on the release channel -- or in another browser that's not beta?

Comment: Well, that's why I tested in Safari and FF. FF is 17 and Safari is Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17).

Comment: Same issue here, both on Firefox and Chromium. Cleaning cookies didn't help. (Should I create my own bug report?) Thank in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have once logged into chat a long time ago with a previous account. That account was merged together with your current one (on Stack Overflow itself). Simply said, chat wasn't sure which of the two you are, and thus decided on "neither".

This is cleared up now, so you should be able to chat.

Comment: I personally still have the issue.

Comment: @JeromeJ Try again now.

Comment: @balpha Hooray! Thank you!

Comment: @balpha, I think I am having the same login problem with chat. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: @QuestionOverflow No, you don't. All your chat accounts are in good condition. What is it that doesn't work and what happens?

Comment: @balpha, the same problem mentioned by Jiskiras. I just could not log into chat even though I am logged into Stack Exchange and I can see my user name. Whenever, I click the chat link on the top menu bar, I got logged out. I guess it is the browser problem. I was using Firefox 19.0 earlier on and that didn't work. I tried Chrome and now it works. Seems chat.stackoverflow doesn't like Firefox users :)

Comment: how to do clear my previous accounts chat...so just give me proper solution..i cant chat with anyone.i m able to see all chatroom but cant chat...i also cleared my all browser and this problem is occur in all browser.